# Having trouble with java packages/setting classpath

Tags: java

I usually don't have any problems setting up the classpath and running programs, but I'm running into a bit of a problem.  I'm working on a program that will download a series of reports.  If the working directory is called Report downloader, my project resides in

```
src/org/report/reportdownloader
```

and the jar files I'm working with reside in

```
lib/
```

When I'm going to compile my project (I'm in windows :( ) I type in

```
javac -classpath .;..\..\..\..\..\lib.transfer.jar; ..\..\..\..\..\lib.someotherjar.jar; ReportGrabber.java ReportDriver.java
```

I get an error message saying

```
ReportDriver.java:12: error:package com.transfer does not exist
import com.transfer.*;
^
1 error
```

And I don't really understand why.  I'm trying to import a valid package, and I showed it where to find the jar in the classpath and it's still giving me grief.

I'm losing my mind, I feel so dumb for asking about this.  I could give up and just use eclipse but I really want to figure this out.

EDIT: When I type

```
java -cp .;..\..\..\..\lib\transfer.jar; ..\..\..\..\lib\someotherjar.jar; ReportDriver
```

to run the file, I get an error saying

```
Error: could not find or load main class ..\..\..\..\lib\someotherjar.jar;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You realize your classpath has a lib.transfer.jar and not lib\transfer.jar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are there 5 **..** instead of 4?

to access your **lib** directory from **reportdownloader**, you have to do

```
..\..\..\..\lib
```

not

```
..\..\..\..\..\lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a relative path seems like a bad idea to me.

Why not do this:

```
... -classpath /lib/transfer.jar /lib/someother.jar
```

or in windows:

```
... -classpath c:\lib\transfer.jar c:\lib\someother.jar
```